# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error - Config File path doesn't exist

Tags: asp.net, http, iis

Our typical .Net application path on our boxes:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NetApps\AppDir\OurProduct_Release_18.1\SourceDir\LogOnScreen\LogOnScreen\web.config

The .Net application path that started the problem:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NetApps\AppDir**OurProduct_Bad-Missing-path**\SourceDir\LogOnScreen\LogOnScreen\web.config

When I'm in debug in VS 2015 or VS 2017 and the code blows up, I get this "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" screen that pops up instead of a pointer in the code itself telling me where the issue is and a 'stack trace' of sorts. Please see the screenshot, sorry for the blur, I can't put up anything proprietary or I'll get in trouble!

It started when I brought down 'OurProduct_Release_18.2' (which a team mate had made changes and committed it using VS 2017 which is Framework 4.7 and C# 7.0) and I opened it using VS 2015 (Framework 4.7 and not C# 7.0) and I did a Rebuild on the entire solution. It flagged some code because of the differences in the C# code version. No biggie right?

I deleted the version I brought down starting at "OurProduct_Bad-Missing-path" on. The "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\NetApps\AppDir\" folder path always stays. When we work on something we pull down 'prod' and put in in under 'AppDir'. That is just the prod-relative-path we use in production so that's why we do it.

That is when I started getting the "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error" window instead of Visual Studio just showing me where the code blew up anytime I had code blow up. Just typical code-dev work: Run, blowup, fix, run, all good, on to next item, run, blow up, fix, all good... etc...

I did a scan of my entire hard drive for the bad/deleted path (actually just the 'OurProduct_Bad-Missing-path' portion) and found it in several places and files. Mostly in a JetBrains Resharper cache folder path which I have since deleted. I still have the issue. I found it in websites.xml also. I deleted it and restarted my box but still have the issue.

It happens now using VS 2015 & VS 2017 so I'm thinking it is some sort of IIS issue. What can I do to get either VS or IIS to quit looking at that path for the SystemError.aspx screen?

[HTTP Error 500.19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQWko.jpg)

Comment: please ensure that the ApplicationPool user has read permissions on the physical directory hosting your website

Comment: Any IIS user on my box has full access to the Web/App structure we develop under. I'm good there. Thanks MM.

Comment: Please post the fix here so it can be helpful for others

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to imply the issue is fixed. I meant that the permissions are pretty wide-open.